# Excel interop CopyFromRecordset/ADODB (custom data/no database) in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, adodb, excel-interop, asp.net-core-6.0

We have this poor man's weekly task, which essentially loads a bunch of CSVs, massages them a bit, dumps them into preloaded Excel template and sends them as an attachment to mgmt. Then they play with it using excel filters and charts, etc (not important here).

What is important is that this used to be a .NET Framework app which we have to migrate to .net core, and the initial author did this by constructing an `ADODB` recordset and using `CopyFromRecordset` method on a Range to dump the entire table. For example, this constructs the recordset:

```cs
    internal static ADODB.Recordset ConvertToADODBRecordSet(this List<MyData> data)
    {
        var result = new ADODB.Recordset { CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient };

        var resultFields = result.Fields;
        resultFields.Append("Date", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate);
        resultFields.Append("Hour", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
        resultFields.Append("Code", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 16);


        result.Open(CursorType: ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockType: ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic);

        foreach (var dr in data)
        {
            result.AddNew();
            resultFields[0].Value = dr.Date;
            resultFields[1].Value = dr.Hour;
            resultFields[2].Value = dr.Code;
        }

        return result;
    }

...

var table = sheet.ListObjects["CodesTable"];
table.InsertRowRange.CopyFromRecordset(data.ConvertToADODBRecordSet());
```

As far as I see, there is not ADODB support in .net framework, I couldn't even try it with supported database objects because, well, there is no database here, recordset is manual and judging by other peoples' attempts it wouldn't work anyway. Entering values in cells one by one is not feasible, there are a dozen sets, each with over 100K rows, it takes forever.

So, how does one go about injecting a manual range of values in Excel using a single call C# interop on .net core?

PS: I cannot use any library which directly just modifies xlsx file. Upon injecting data, a bunch of charts and pivot tables are refreshed by Excel, so whatever alternative solution might come up, it needs to act as a full Excel and update all the sheets before saving.

Comment: You may consider using NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), [ClosedXml](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml), etc... instead of Excel interop.

Comment: @user9938, nope, its not a web server. Its a console app that is ran through scheduler once a week. The interop is working just fine through .net framework, the issue here is missing ADODB in .net core.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core) NuGet package? Here is an [example](https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/XlsIO-Examples).

Comment: @chen, that's a paid product, and we already pay a ton for Office product, we need to make it work. Its hard to pass this cost, because it was already working on framework.

Comment: Maybe you can edit the .csproj of your .NET Core project and add the generated references from the .NET Framework project to the tag.

Comment: @Chen, doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution, in case anyone needs it. I have abandoned the data transfer route and leaned on clipboard to do the job. "Copying" tab delimited data and then pasting it in the table inject region did the trick. You will however have to convert the pure .net console project into `*-windows` targeted project and add `OutputType` of `WinExe` and `UseWindowsForms` to `true` (or WPF) so that `Clipboard` class can be available (its not in pure console project). You do not have to create any forms or `Run` the winForms/WPF though, just let it run as console app in `Main`.

```
    using var writer = new StringWriter();
    var cfg = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"))
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
        Delimiter = "\t"
    };
    using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, cfg);
    csv.WriteRecords(data);

    var dataObject = new DataObject();
    dataObject.SetText(writer.ToString());
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);

    // paste to excel
    var table = sheet.ListObjects["CodesTable"];
    table.InsertRowRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd);
```